# Android captive portal after login redirection

Tags: javascript, android, captiveportal

i have the following problem that i could not figure out: i've created a captive portal when people connects to my hotel's wifi, in some Androids devices - the "sign up" splash page closes after receiving 204 response in the end of the login - but in some Androids it stays open and you can continue browsing , and in this case i want them to be redirected to my hotel's homepage.

i build up the homepage and on window load i try and change location to a page i know will respond 204 , and counting on that, that the sign up process will close. but in the cases that it does not close the homepage stays stuck - how can i implement these two different states?

Answer (score 0):

Android 5.0+( Starting from Lollipop ) have the default behavior of `splash page closing after receiving 204 response in the end of the login`. However in older Android phones before Lollipop the hotspot page stays up.

The behavior is controlled by Android OS. User doesn't seem to have easy way to control the behavior.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933146/prevent-captive-portal-auto-close-after-authentication-android) is more detailed discussion about the issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: how do you know from which Android version it has this behavior ??? i looked endlessly online in order to find that data! :)

Comment: We are in the same boat buddy :D :D I am also searching for some way to hold that captive portal on android devices. I found simillar thread while searching on google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933146/prevent-captive-portal-auto-close-after-authentication-android But it seems like there is no way we can do that